# Express.js Parse Body as Text for One Route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Using express.js, I am parsing all the request bodies as json (`app.use(express.json())`). I have a single route where I want to parse the body as text, instead of json. How do I create an exception (i.e., parse body as text) for a single route?

Comment: You can set up multiple parsers, and express will parse based on the request's content-type afaik. However, why not simply send `{ "text": "..." }` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Chris G mentioned it's a question of the Content-Type header.

According to [doc](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json) by default express.json middleware looks only to `Content-Type: application/json` hense if client send other value `Content-Type: text/plain` the json middleware will not parse it...